# Автоподгонка изображений в div

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Представьте посты ВКонтакте. Независимо от количества и размеров картинок, они распределяться по div ровно.
Как правильно это сделать и вообще, как это реализована в самом ВК?
Возможно ли это сделать только в CSS или как то нужно пошаманить в JS?
В общем жду Ваших мыслей и возможно кодов:)
[image: Пример блока]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не представляю посты вконтакте, прикрепи скриншот что-ли, не все люди сидят вконтакте

Comment: Добавил скрин:)

Comment: Нашел некий пример, почти то что нужно, но там выравнивается по ширине, а вот по высоте чет не то. http://tympanus.net/Development/GammaGallery/

Answer (score 1):

> и вообще, как это реализована в самом ВК?

Когда смотрел, как это реализовано в ВК, пришел к следующему:

1. У ВК есть стандартные размещения для 1, 2, ..., N прикреплений к записи. Т.е. если прикрепили 2 фотки, то запись отображается с одним стилем дивов, если 5 фоток, то они отображаются с другим стилем - с красивом размещением для 5 фоток, и т.д.
2. Сами дивы установлены определенного размера, а картинки ставятся на background-image. Фотка там центрируется и лишнее фотки (из-за разных соотношений) просто не показывается.

Такое построение блоков считаю оптимальным, со скриптами такое будет хуже выглядеть. Стили фоток можете посмотреть на самом ВК.

Comment: В коде ВК лишь img завернутый в тег <a>. Это и так ясно, что используется алгоритм с определенными стилями. Но я думаю, что фишка в размерах картинок и js. То есть как то нужно определить размер картинки и если она в рамках той или иной конфиги, то выводить в определенном стиле. Но как все это связывать между всеми картинками, это сколько возможных вариантов О_о

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div + div + div {
  width: 33.333%;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 67%;
}
```

```html
<div style=background-image:url(//placekitten.com/300/300)>
</div><div style=background-image:url(//placekitten.com/300/300)>
</div><div style=background-image:url(//placekitten.com/300/300)>
</div><div style=background-image:url(//placekitten.com/300/300)>
</div><div style=background-image:url(//placekitten.com/300/300)>
</div>
```

Comment: Не то, нужен JS который автоматически будет подгонять картинки в блоке, в зависимости от размеров и количества самих картинок.

Comment: @Альберт, на приведённых скриншотах подгонки по размерам нет. А как сделать по количеству видно из ответа.